# Upgrade from rails 3 to rails 4 with capistrano, now image assets are not showing. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

Upgraded from Rails 3 to 4, and now the image assets aren't showing in production.  It appears that the javascript and css files are working ok.

I've tried the steps at https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Upgrading-to-Rails-4 but it doesn't help.

I've tried deleting the json files and yml files in my shared/assets folder, but it still doesn't show the images once the deploy finishes.

If I try to view an image on the site in a new tab, I get the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." error.

I've tried this:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

and this:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

in the config/application.rb file.  Neither work.

Here's what I have in my config/environments/production.rb file:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
config.assets.compile = false
config.assets.digest = true
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

The Capfile:

```
load 'deploy'
load 'deploy/assets'
load 'config/deploy'
```

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the images to show up in production?

Comment: can you specify which assets you mean? i think that rails4 only creates assets with fingerprints, so if you reference images etc directly (some_image.png) they are missing in production.

Comment: I mean all of the images in my app/assets/images directory....

Comment: and how are you requesting those? give an example url.

Comment: `http://mysite.com/assets/logo-staging.jpg` gives a The page you were looking for doesn't exist error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all my bad...I haven't been using the asset pipeline helpers, and now it's biting me.  When I switch to image_tag("whatever.jpg"), it working...

Comment: this was a very helpful question for me! however my app has images rendered as backgrounds of divs through css and those aren't appearing. can't really fix that with `image_tag` ...

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4 no longer creates assets without a digest. So if you are referencing assets (such as images) directly (e.g. `/assets/whatever.jpg`) without a digest in the URL, you will likely get a 404.

non-stupid-digest-assets gem will fix this by creating non-digest assets: https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets/tree/master